# Seaborn distplot errors when generating histograms for single-element series

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

When I use seaborn's [distplot](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) (in 0.7.1) to visualize a histogram, I get an error if the input series contains only a single element. In other words, something like

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

num_elements = 1000
sns.distplot(np.random.normal(10, 1, num_elements))
```

works beautifully but if I set `num_elements` to 1 I get the following error:

```
In [8]: num_elements = 1

In [9]: sns.distplot(np.random.normal(10, 1, num_elements))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-35e3f8293582> in <module>()
----> 1 sns.distplot(np.random.normal(10, 1, num_elements))

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/seaborn/distributions.pyc in distplot(a, bins, hist, kde, rug, fit, hist_kws, kde_kws, rug_kws, fit_kws, color, vertical, norm_hist, axlabel, label, ax)
    207     if hist:
    208         if bins is None:
--> 209             bins = min(_freedman_diaconis_bins(a), 50)
    210         hist_kws.setdefault("alpha", 0.4)
    211         hist_kws.setdefault("normed", norm_hist)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/seaborn/distributions.pyc in _freedman_diaconis_bins(a)
     28     # From http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/798/
     29     a = np.asarray(a)
---> 30     h = 2 * iqr(a) / (len(a) ** (1 / 3))
     31     # fall back to sqrt(a) bins if iqr is 0
     32     if h == 0:

TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

After poking around the source a bit, I found that I could avoid this error by specifying the number of bins. But that opens me up to another one:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-6e6569de737a> in <module>()
----> 1 sns.distplot(np.random.normal(10, 1, num_elements), bins=10)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/seaborn/distributions.pyc in distplot(a, bins, hist, kde, rug, fit, hist_kws, kde_kws, rug_kws, fit_kws, c\olor, vertical, norm_hist, axlabel, label, ax)
    213         hist_color = hist_kws.pop("color", color)
    214         ax.hist(a, bins, orientation=orientation,
--> 215                 color=hist_color, **hist_kws)
    216         if hist_color != color:
    217             hist_kws["color"] = hist_color

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.pyc in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1817                     warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1818                                   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1819             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1820         pre_doc = inner.__doc__
   1821         if pre_doc is None:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.pyc in hist(self, x, bins, range, normed, weights, cumulative, bottom, histtype, align, orientation, rwidth, log, color, label, stacked, **kwargs)
   5933             x = np.array([[]])
   5934         else:
-> 5935             x = _normalize_input(x, 'x')
   5936         nx = len(x)  # number of datasets
   5937

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.pyc in _normalize_input(inp, ename)
   5875                 else:
   5876                     raise ValueError(
-> 5877                         "{ename} must be 1D or 2D".format(ename=ename))
   5878                 if inp.shape[1] < inp.shape[0]:
   5879                     warnings.warn(

ValueError: x must be 1D or 2D
```

What's going on here? Is there some workaround I can use to force seaborn to plot a histogram for this single element series? For context, I need this because I'm plotting multiple histograms, describing different conditions, on a shared axis. In some cases, there might be only a single element in that condition, yet I ought to be able to plot just the one bar!

Comment: I'd consider `array([ 10.37823942])` to be a single element series. Further, `tmp = np.random.normal(10, 1, 1); assert tmp is np.atleast_1d(tmp)` runs without error, indicating that that `np.atleast_1d` returns the same object back.

Comment: Also, on the topic of scalars in numpy, note that `tmp` has `shape` of `(1,)` and a `len` of `1`. I can convert to a real scalar -- to demonstrate that numpy makes this distinction -- with `np.asscalar`, which no longer has shape or length.

Comment: Yep you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trick `seaborn` when the array length is 1 by duplicating the value:

```
rs = np.random.RandomState(0)
num_elements = 1
x = rs.normal(10, 1, num_elements)
sns.distplot(np.r_[x, x], kde=False, norm_hist=True)
```

[image: seaborn histogram]

Or if you don't need the goodies provided by seaborn (most of them doesn't make sense for a single element) just use matplotlib or pandas:

```
plt.hist(x, bins=1)
```

[image]

```
pd.Series(x).hist(bins=1);
```

[image]

Comment: Nice workaround. Unfortunately this means I've got to normalize, or accept a doubled count. A related workaround that works in my case involves  restricting the range of bars (e.g. `bars=range(0, max_value, bin_size)`) and then adding an element to the dataset at, say `max_value+1`. I'd still love to find a direct solution, though.

Comment: Note that I'm making several calls to `distplot` in a loop, to plot an overlapping set of histograms in the same axis covering a variety of conditions. I'm using seaborn's features in these plots, but need to be able to plot a single element series because, in some figures, one of the conditions will have only a single element. Also, this use case precludes normalization.

Comment: If you're not drawing the KDE (and hence not using normalization) and specifying the bin size (and hence not using the reference rule default) then there is no functional difference between `sns.distplot` and `ax.hist`.

Comment: @ohruunuruus I don't understand the problem. You posted a bit of code that didn't work. If it worked I would expect it to create a plot like my first one (modulo style). I that's not what you expected please clarify. The other two are alternatives that may or may not work for you depending on your actual needs, which are unknown to me. Based on the information you provided that's as far as I can go.

Comment: @Goyo and @mwaskom you're right that `plt.hist()` will actually suffice in this case. My issue with your `sns.distplot()` solution is that it involves normalization of the data, which isn't acceptable in my use case. But `plt.hist()` works with my inputs out of the box. Still, it's very unsatisfying that `sns.distplot()` can't operate with a single-element series -- a bug IMHO.

Comment: Sorry you're so unsatisfied with the software and technical support you're getting for free.

Comment: @mwaskom sorry... didn't mean to offend, and not really sure where the hostility is coming from. If you're a seaborn developer then thanks for your work; you've done a great job producing something that dramatically improves upon previous visualization capabilities in python. I don't think it's unreasonable to expect modules to work robustly under a broad set of circumstances -- not because I think I'm entitled to anything for free, but because I think the open-source movement is important and the code it produces must meet the highest of standards. If I can create a fix, I'll offer it freely.

Comment: @ohruunuruus My answer deals with the problem as explained in the question --arrays of shape (1,) and I think it leads to a correct plot in that case. It's not meant to be applied to other data because that's not what you asked and it didn't look like you needed help with that. The fact that seaborn does not work with this kind of data out of the box might be a bug but fixing it is out of the scope of SO, there are other means to file and discuss bug reports and patches.

Comment: @Goyo yes, as I said above using `plt.hist` does work for me, which is why I accepted. The `distplot` solution does not work because I can't normalize the plot (I acknowledge this is not in the original question, but I have been quite explicit about it in the comments). So let's review: you answered, we discussed, I accepted, and made a note that I think this is a bug. Why am I getting a hard time because I think it's a bug? I know SO is not going to fix the bug. Did I indicate that I thought otherwise? Honestly, I'm astonished that this conversation is continuing. Am I being trolled here??